# Nginx: Can't open any links on website. Only homepage display

Tags: php, nginx, webserver

I have got a website run on Nginx. I've got a problem because the homepage is loading ok, but I can not access any another link through the homepage- nothing happens.

```
    server {
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  root /usr/share/nginx/example.com;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

 location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
               fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
               fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/example.com$fastcgi_script_name;
               include        fastcgi_params;
            }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example/com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
```

Nginx doesn't show LOGS for that issue.

Comment: website slug changes when i enter a links, but nothing display

Answer (score 0):

Remove all default NGinx files in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*`, you may have problems if this config is active.

Verify it has the following line on `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

Create a new file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/exemple.com.conf` and try:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_exemple.com.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_ssl_exemple.com.log;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example/com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # Not found this on disk?
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
        break;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    # Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    # listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-fastcgi.sock;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on; # to support 404s for PHP files not found
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Static files.
    # Set expire headers, Turn off access log
    location ~* \favicon.ico$ {
        access_log off;
        expires 1d;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location ~ ^/(img|cjs|ccss)/ {
        access_log off;
        expires 7d;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    # Deny access to .htaccess files,
    # git & svn repositories, etc
    location ~ /(\.ht|\.git|\.svn) {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```